# Is it possible to gain code coverage for constructors with unit tests?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Say I have these private fields and this constructor...

```
    private readonly ILogger<KafkaFactory<T>> _logger;
    private readonly IKafkaConfig _kafkaConfig;
    private readonly IOptionsMonitor<IKafkaConfig>? _kafkaConfigMonitor = null;
    private readonly string? _configName = null;
    private IKafkaConfig Options => _configName == null ? _kafkaConfigMonitor?.CurrentValue ?? _kafkaConfig : _kafkaConfigMonitor!.Get(_configName);

    public KafkaFactory(ILogger<KafkaFactory<T>> logger, IOptionsMonitor<IKafkaConfig> kafkaConfig, string name)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _kafkaConfigMonitor = kafkaConfig;
        _configName = name;
        _kafkaConfig = kafkaConfig.Get(name);
        _logger.LogInformation("{class} using named options {options}", nameof(KafkaFactory<T>), Options);
    }
```

How do I cover this code with unit tests? Is this even possible?

Comment: What do you think "coverage" means, exactly?

Comment: Your fields _don't_ need to be nullable, nor pre-initialized to `null`.

Comment: @Dai to ensure expected behavior paths of the method under test. Given some input, we expect some output. The only thing I can think to test her is whether the constructor successfully creates a new instance of the class, meaning the instance would not be null.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to test whether the constructor has set the private fields to the correct values? Welcome to Stack Overflow BTW. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).